# Excel Table Mis-Aligned Column headers

Tags: python

I have the following code that takes a dataframe *dem* and creates a formal table in Excel with the data contained in the dataframe. The one issue that I am running into is the headers are not aligned because of the index column. Screenshot of the issue below - notice how Student is over the Index column and everything is misaligned because of this.

Where is the issue in this code? Do I need to reset the index or something?

```
destination = shutil.copy2(demnote, dnotearch)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(demnote, engine='xlsxwriter')
dem.to_excel(writer,"Demand")
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet_table_header = writer.sheets['Demand']
end_row = len(dem.index)
end_column = len(dem.columns)
cell_range = xlsxwriter.utility.xl_range(0, 0, end_row, end_column)
header = [{'header': c} for c in dem.columns.tolist()]
worksheet_table_header.add_table(cell_range,{'header_row': True, 'columns':header, 'style':'Table Style Medium 11'})
worksheet_table_header.freeze_panes(1, 1)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the input data?

Comment: The input data is a dataframe called dem that is Student | School | Class | Seat but aligned correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off the index in the dataframe (and you probably should turn off and skip the header row since you are overwriting it:

```py
dem.to_excel(writer, "Demand", startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
```

Here is a full working example from the XlsxWriter [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_table.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':    ['China',    'India',    'United States', 'Indonesia'],
    'Population': [1404338840, 1366938189, 330267887,       269603400],
    'Rank':       [1,          2,          3,               4]})

# Order the columns if necessary.
df = df[['Rank', 'Country', 'Population']]

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_table.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write the dataframe data to XlsxWriter. Turn off the default header and
# index and skip one row to allow us to insert a user defined header.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Create a list of column headers, to use in add_table().
column_settings = [{'header': column} for column in df.columns]

# Add the Excel table structure. Pandas will add the data.
worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {'columns': column_settings})

# Make the columns wider for clarity.
worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 12)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]